# Publishing fails with "Invalid URI: ."

Tags: 2011

I have a page with one multimedia component. When I try to publish the page it fails. When looking at the publish transaction I get the error `Invalid URI: .`.

Answer (score 5):

I used core service to create the component. It seems there is an error in my code that added a metadata component link field with an empty URI. I discovered this by looking at the meta data xml in the content manager database. When I opened the component the content manager GUI did not indicate that the component link field was invalid.

To solve my problem I added a component link in the invalid component link field and saved the component (overwriting the invalid empty component link). Then I reopened the component and removed the component link.

Comment: Not just for empty URIs. I think I recall seeing this also when the Content Porter has had problems and put in a placeholder.

Comment: Indeed, the xlink:href attribute accepts any normalized string when saving, but this always causes problems later on, usually during rendering.